simple_form I18n for input :x, type: :file
Situation
I am using the very common gem simple_form for my forms in my german rails app. I want to localize my file uploads on all of my models.
My problem:
Now it shows in english "Choose File" on the button and "No file chosen" based on the lack of I18n input (see below).

I have no clue on how to change this behaviour. What exactly to chanege in the YML file? Which key? What to insert in below YML file?
From the docs I created a simple_form.de.yml file which reads:
de:
  simple_form:
    ...standard stuff...


Just leave it alone. This input is localized by the browser and while there are various hacks to replace the input with a label or something else it's not worth the accessibility issues they bring. Sometimes it's better to just turn a blind eye.

This means on a german browser it will appear in German? @max

it depends on the browser but Chrome for example seems to use my native language instead of English.

This is the default input type file style.
That text is set from the browser with the language configured on it, not your i18n file.
If you want something translated, and a bit more styled, try this :
<div>
    <input type="file" id="my_file" style="display: none;">
    <label for="my_file" style="background: blue; color: white; padding: 10px; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer;">Upload file</label>
</div>

